# To concatenate an array inside other array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to concatenate an array inside another array.

```
Input = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Output: `['ab', 'cd']`

```
Input = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', '.']]
```

Output: `['ab', 'cd', 'f.']`

Conditions:

- All arrays are string arrays
- The array's length can be any value
- At the end, I should have just one array, not array of arrays

Comment: What difficulty are you having writing a loop and creating a new list? Do you know how to join strings in a single list into a single string? Also unclear if you want to modify the input list or return a new one

Comment: Off-topic: Note that in Python, those are called lists not arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be decourage as a beginner, asking the right question in SO is rly diffcult - here is a simple list comprehension solution with a string join:

```
input = [["a","b"], ['c','d']]

[''.join(list) for list in input]
```

Output: ['ab', 'cd']

As suggested by @ChaddRobertson here is the same solution with an easier to understandable for-each loop:

```
ouput_list = []
for list in input:
    ouput_list.append(''.join(list))
    
print(ouput_list)
```

Comment: List comprehension might not be the best method if somebody is just starting out - perhaps include a traditional loop in your answer, as they are often easier to visualize.

Comment: You are right - I also added a solution with a foreach loop

Comment: Nice answer but try to avoid naming variables after data types and built ins - `list`

Comment: ... The downvote arrow says "This question does not show any research effort", which this one clearly does not (see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)). Encouraging, upvoting and answering questions that break rules and turn this site into "do my job for me" is a problem, even if those questions are asked by new users.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - I think this quite a bit of bias on your part; you used SO for 10 years - you know the ins and outs of SO;  As a Newbie you don't rly know the mentioned link in your 1st comment (except the tour) - SO also doesn't show then too you if you post your 1st question, therefore how should he know that in his first question? I thought it a reasonable question this is also why I upvoted the question from -1 to 0.  ...

Comment: ... What does it say about a beginner who is struggling to learn a programming language for the first time and now there are also too stupid to ask a question? 
With the concept of upvoting for "research effort" i wasn't aware, after you pointed it noticed the tooltip - so thanks for that.

Comment: This has been a topic of extensive discussion over on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=new+user+asking). Additionally, the ask page has a [helpful sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz9it.png) containing the same links in my (and others') canned responses to new users who do not appear to have read those links. Downvotes are not a personal indictment of the user that receives them -- just that your submission does not follow SO's guidelines https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/843953

Answer (score 0):

You could use map to apply a join to all the sublists:

```
[*map(''.join,Input)]


['ab', 'cd']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [["a", "b", "c"],["c","d"], ["x", "y", "z"]]

newL = []

for i in L:
    newL.append("".join(i))

print(newL)
```

This is what you need for.